# Why does MQTT not connect to the server?

Tags: django, django-models, mqtt

My purpose is to achieve MQTT message publish upon postsave signal sent my DJango models. I have registered on_connect, on disconnect, on_publish callbacks to check when the relevant process is executed. However, none of callbacks I registered works. Here is my post_save signal code.
Can someone please give me a hint where I do mistake?

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("connecting")
    print("client:"+str(client))
    print("userdata:"+str(userdata))
    print("flags:"+str(flags))
    print("result:"+str(rc))
    global flag_connected
    flag_connected=1


def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("message published")


def on_connect_fail(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("failed to connect")
    print("client:"+str(client))
    print("userdata:"+str(userdata))
    print("flags:"+str(flags))
    print("result:"+str(rc))
    global flag_connected
    flag_connected=0


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
   global flag_connected
   flag_connected = 0



  

def notify_windowsApp(sender,instance, **kwargs):
    

    new_truck_registered={
        "identity":str(instance.truck_identity),
        "doorName":str(instance.registered_door.door_name),
        "doorNumber":str(instance.registered_door.door_number),
        "entryTag":str(instance.entry_tag),
       
        #"depatureTag":str(instance.departure_tag), 
        "entrytime":instance.entry_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d::%H-%M'),

    }



    



    sendToClient(new_truck_registered)


def sendToClient(payloadTobeSent):
    

    client=mqtt.Client(client_id="django_post_save_signal",
    clean_session=True, )
    mqttBroker="broker.hivemq.com"
    client.on_connect=on_connect
    client.on_publish=on_publish
    client.on_connect_fail=on_connect_fail
    client.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
    client.connect(mqttBroker)
    client.publish('baydoor/truckentrance',payload=str(payloadTobeSent),qos=1, retain=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no `on_connect_fail` callback in the [docs](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#callbacks), where did you get that from?

And more importantly, you have not started the client [network loop](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#network-loop) so none of the callbacks will ever get called.

Comment: thanks. My main question is where to start the network loop. Can I start and stop before connect function and after publish function?

Comment: Yes, there is a callback named `on_connect_fail` in client.py. "If implemented, called when the client failed to connect to the broker."